# Angular JS parent controller unable to pass alone variables to child controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to share two variables across 2 different controllers, one nested into another:

approach1:

```
<body ng-controller="WGHomeLanCtrl">
    <section><div><a>{{text}}</a></div></section>
    <section>...</section>
    <section ng-controller="WGHomeSurveyCtrl"> <div> <a>{{lan}} and {{lan2}}</a></div></section>
```

In my controller file, I have:

```
var HomeControllers = angular.module('HomeControllers', []);
HomeControllers.controller('WGHomeLanCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.lan = "en";

    $http.get("lan/lan_".concat($scope.lan, ".json")).success(function(data) {
        $scope.text = data;
    });


HomeControllers.controller('WGHomeSurveyCtrl', ['$scope', 
    function($scope) {
    $scope.lan2= $scope.text;
    $scope.lan = $scope.$parent.lan;
}]);
```

The actual result is that, the {{text}} in the parent controller is showing up, meaning that the $http part is working fine. in the child scope, the {{lan}} is showing correct value too; however the {{lan2}} is not showing correct; the {{lan2}} is shown as plain text.

Any thoughts why?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`text` gets updated after the `lan2` is assigned the value of `text` because of the $http call delay, so `lan2` becomes whatever `text` is at that point.

The simplest solution would be to just use `{{text}}` in your view. However, if it's not an option (if, for example, `text` might be used for something else and changed) then you can add a watcher or emit a message and update `lan2` whenever the `text` is updated.

Btw. all your parent scope's variables should be available inside children scopes.

Comment: if the $http call cause delay, the {{text}} shouldn't be showing up in the parent scope? In the child scope I need to do something with the {{text}} so I can't just use it in the child scope, have to some sort store the {{text}} in the child scope first